# Projecting javascript object members into an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have an object as follows:

```
asset: {
    images []
}
```

Images look like this:

```
image {
    width,
    height,
    fileName
}
```

I need to project all of the image filenames into an array. The obvious implementation is the following:

```
var fileNames = [];
var i;
for (i = 0; i < asset.images.length; i++) {
    fileNames.push(asset.images[i].fileName);
}
```

Does anybody know of a fancy way to do this in 1 or 2 lines? You can use jQuery or angularJs

Comment: You might want to look into https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map.

Answer (score 1):

```
var fileNames = asset.images.map(function(i) {
  return i.fileName;
});
```

That is the quickest way to run a set of instructions over each element of an array.

Comment: OP want _to do this in 1 or 2 lines_ but you have 3 :-D

Comment: @Grundy you can put it all on 1 line - but I prefer to use 3 lines for readability.

Answer (score 0):

```
asset.images.map(function(i) {return i.fileName;};);
```

```js
var asset = {};
asset.images = [];
asset.images.push({fileName: "test1"});
asset.images.push({fileName: "test2"});
asset.images.push({fileName: "test3"});
asset.images.push({fileName: "test4"});


alert(asset.images.map(function(i) {return i.fileName;}));
```

Comment: `Ignored call to 'alert()'. The document is sandboxed, and the 'allow-modals' keyword is not set.`

Comment: Where do you get this message ? On chromium 45.0 the alert is shown

Comment: Chrome 46.0.2490.80 m

Comment: @Grundy : http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308672/alerts-no-longer-work-in-stackoverflow-snippets-in-chrome-46

Comment: Works for me. I get the alert. Running Chrome version 46.0.2490.80 m.